# MariaDB Trigger Calculating Time Difference as a decimal of total hours and tenth of hour always rounding up

Tags: sql, casting, mariadb, rounding, database-trigger

I have a table that contains these columns:

```
start_time datetime
end_time datetime
billable_time decimal(3,1)
```

The `billable_time` column is calculated with a trigger on insert and update as the total number of hours and tenth of hour as a decimal; however, I want it to always round up the decimal as opposed to rounding to the nearest digit. When creating the trigger, I cannot figure out how to make it always round up the decimal. This trigger calculates it correctly, but it rounds it down if that is the nearest digit:

```
SET new.billable_time = CAST(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(new.end_time, new.start_time))/3600 as decimal(3,1))
```

For example:

```
start time = 2020-06-01 11:00:00
end_time = 2020-06-01 12:22:08
```

Results in

```
billable_time = 1.4
```

But it should be 1.5 if it always rounds up.

I have tried using the `CEIL()` and `CEILING()` functions, but they round it up to the nearest integer, which is 2.

I cannot seem to figure out how to make it do what I want. Is it possible to do this in a trigger? Any help would be greatly appreciated. The database is MariaDB v10.4.13.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to add half of a tenth of second to the value before `cast`ing it:

```
SET new.billable_time = CAST(
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(new.end_time, new.start_time))/3600 + 0.05 
    AS decimal(3,1)
)
```

You can also use `ceil()`: the idea is to first divide by `360` instead of `3600`, then round with `ceil()`, and finally divide by `10`:

```
SET new.billable_time = 
    CEIL(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(new.end_time, new.start_time))/360) / 10
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I tried both solutions though and they both still return 1.4?

Comment: @jamesg546: `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2020-06-01 12:22:08', '2020-06-01 11:00:00'))/3600` returns `1.3689`, so this is rounded to `1.4`.

Comment: You are correct. I was making a stupid arithmetic mistake in my head. 6*4=24 and for some reason I was thinking 6*4=21. Thank you so much for your help and sorry for my confusion. Lol.